# startx command not working in MobaXterm

Tags: raspbian, gui, startx

I have set up Raspbian Jessie on my RPi 3 Model B. I am using [mobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) as a remote client. To start the Pi's GUI, when I type `startx`, the following output is returned:

[image]

Comment: Use the command "startlxde" instead of startx

Answer (score 1):

That won't work, because the Pi doesn't know how to run X on Microsoft Windows.  It needs some help on the Windows side to connect to an X server there.

The topic was discussed in [mapping startx screen back to my pc laptop](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=20479) (with one response providing step-by-step instructions) and is explained in [MobaXterm's features page](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/features.html) under the heading ***X11 server***:

> When you run a SSH, TELNET or RLOGIN/RSH session you will be able to display your remote applications directly on your local Windows PC. In a SSH session, there is no need to set the "DISPLAY" variable as MobaXterm uses *X11-forwarding* in order to ease and secure your work.